# VBA Excel Issue - Opening Folders and Files using criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Currently trying to work on a VBA script to use with a new report I've created. The problem is to fully do this report it requires the information from 224 individual reports each month.

Now I can go and manually extract the information but VBA would be a quicker option. All information is downloaded and stored in individual folders representing shop names and then broken down further by months.
(C:Folder\Reports\ShopName\January) etc.

What I'd like to be able to do is set a criteria or atleast create a option that searches for the folders with ShopName and Month as determined by the user at the start of the form. (They simple type both details into an area of the spreadsheet) The VBA would then go and export the information from the relevant folders and files.

I can run the VBA to format, select and present the data I need, but I can't work out how to get the VBA to go into these folders on its own.

I wrote a VBA check to see if the folders exist but this is with me defining the location in the macro.

> In this Example I am just checking if folders exist
>
> ```
> Sub sbCheckingIfAFolderExists()
>
> Dim FSO
> Dim sFolder As String
>
> sFolder = "W:\Simon Docs\Shop Reports\Weston Favell\Jan" 
> Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>
> If FSO.FolderExists(sFolder) Then
> MsgBox "Specified Folder Is Available", vbInformation, "Exists!"
> Else
> MsgBox folder & "Specified Folder Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found!"
> End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

What I need to change in the above is where Weston Favell\Jan is...that needs to be =A1\=A2 if that makes sense? A1 and A2 being the user input locations they want to extract.

Any help anyone could give would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the shop name and month can be added as variables to the statement you wrote:

```
Sub sbCheckingIfAFolderExists()

Dim FSO
Dim sFolder As String
Vshop = Range("B1").value
Vmonth = Range("B2").value

sFolder = "W:\Simon Docs\Shop Reports\" & Vshop & "\" & Vmonth 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If FSO.FolderExists(sFolder) Then
MsgBox "Specified Folder Is Available", vbInformation, "Exists!"
Else
MsgBox folder & "Specified Folder Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found!"
End If

End Sub
```